# Exchange 2010 immediate bounceback no generated server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I am having some problems with emailing to a couple of specific gmail addresses, but not all gmail addresses.  I'm running Exchange 2010.  Here is the error:

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server:

agmailaddress@gmail.com
# #MAILTO#

Reporting-MTA: dns; EXCH

Final-recipient: X-MAILTO; agmailaddress@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.4.0
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: That error looks funny.. have you mangled/rewritten the output?

Comment: Full Error:                                                                             Generating server:
agmailaddress@gmail.com
# #MAILTO#

--_002_7880678070687665717270757274697875807175707870777367707_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable   --_002_7880678070687665717270757274697875807175707870777367707_--

--_000_7880678070687665717270757274697875807175707870777367707_
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; EXCH

Final-recipient: X-MAILTO; agmailaddress@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.4.0

Comment: I just modified the email address...

Answer (score 0):

Errors like these are usually problems related to DNS resolution.

Try to run nslookup locally on your exchange server:

```
set type=mx
gmail.com
```

Look at the results (run the gmail.com query several times), and see if stays coherent. Check with an outside client against a different DNS server and see if it matches.

Comment: OK, it seems to stay the same.  What do you think my next step should be?  Would it help to flush the DNS cache?

Comment: OK, I'm noticing that doing the gmail.com nslookup from inside is giving me my server name and address, and then the FQDNs of the gmail servers.  From outside, I get server and address unknown and the FQDNs of the gmail servers.

Comment: Server address is just the DNS server you're using, so that should be different. I guess you'll just have to dig in your logfiles.

Comment: That just means that externally nslookup can't resolve the name from the ip address of the DNS server you're running nslookup against. It's completely normal and doesn't have any bearing on DNS resolution.